# Accessing a public variable from another class?

Tags: java, android

The app I'm currently developing has more than one class created, with a corresponding
.xml file for each. My app requires progressing from one screen to the next
after a calculation has been completed.

In one class, I have declared a public double called V, which is the result
of a voltage calculation.

When the user presses "NEXT", a new class (ed: Activity?) is called, and the xml file will change the screen view to a new layout.

In this new class, I need to use the variable (double V) for a new calculation.

I thought that if a variable was public, it could be used anywhere in the package. Do I need to import this variable, or re-declare it somehow?

Any answers would be much appreciated. I've tried everything that I can think of, but
Eclipse just keeps saying V cannot be resolved.

Comment: Did you import the class? And did you refer to V properly? Also, is V an instance variable or a static one?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming by "a new class is called", you're talking about launching a new Activity with an Intent, like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Assuming this is the case, you can just pass the variable along as an extra in the Intent object, and then retrieve it from the newly launched Activity. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("voltage", V);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, within your Activity2.java document, in your onCreate(), add this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double V;
//return -1 if unable to retrieve
if(intent != null) V = intent.getDoubleExtra("voltage", -1);
```

Then V should be populated with the correct voltage value.

Comment: Just tried the code, And eclipse lets me put the code in the first class (Activity), but when i open up the next class, i get an error saying " getExtra(String) is undefined??? It will only let me put the first 2 lines in without an error, but if i eliminate the "if(intent etc. etc) i still cant use variable "V".

Comment: Whoops! Yeah, I mixed that up. `putExtra` allows many different types of parameters, but you do have to specify which type to retrieve. I've updated my answer. :)